# Spanned CSS style/color

Tags: android, kotlin, spanned

Is there any way to use spanned colors directly from a string without using any Java/Kotlin code?
For example to bold text I can use `"<b> $someString </b>"`
But what is the way to change color? I searched it in Android Documentation and I found [this.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#formatting-strings)

> `CSS style: <span style=”color|background_color|text-decoration”>`

But I don't get it how to set it, I tried to do it in many ways e.g.
`"<span style=#999999|#999999|#999999> $someString </span>"`
But it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The character `|` means `or`.

In the documentation you see `<span style=”color|background_color|text-decoration”>`

Which means it can be any of `<span style="color:#999999"> $someString </span>`

Or `<span style="background-color:#999999"> $someString </span>`

Or `<span style="text-decoration:underline"> $someString </span>`

Comment: This is utterly wrong. | doesnt mean OR in this context and these are NOT exclusive so your examples are misleading again. Don't propagate guesses.

Comment: @NickCardoso inline Style attribute doesn't work anyway, but that was not the main problem with this question, if you read the question you will understand their problem was misunderstanding the way Android documentation is written which I clarified for them and as you can see they have accepted it as an on point answer.

Comment: @NickCardoso can you tell me what does `|` mean in this context?!

Answer (score 1):

Luckily i just had to do this for work! What i did was use

```
Html.fromHtml(""<b> $someString </b>"", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

The above is API v24 and above, to do this on older android Devices you would need to use

`SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString("Some Text");`

To change the appearance You can use

`spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 2, SpannableString.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);`
That will increase the size of characters 0-2 in the string you provided, by 2 fold.

Which for me resulted in:
[image: Example SpannableString]